# Laravel/Eloquent save validation with parent/child relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have a parent model which must never exist without at least one associated hasMany relation.  I am attempting to write validation for the model to ensure this never happens.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
        // reject model with no children
        if (count($workflow->children) === 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("need at least one child");
        }
    });
}
```

But now I have a chicken and egg problem.  I can't write the child record without the parent id.  And I can't write the parent record until the save validation passes.  But when I try to associate the children and call ->push() on the parent model, I get various issues depending on how I try to associate the two.

The following causes a FK constraint failure on the child column which references the parent:

```
$parent->children->add($child);
$child->parent()->associate($parent);
$parent->push();
```

Is Laravel just too stupid to handle this (seemingly reasonable) use case?

Comment: First of all, FK constraint is _issue_ of your database layer. More code is needed I don't see where you are using `push()`.

Comment: You can't do that with eloquent. It doesn't handle aggregates. Just run transaction with rollback in case no child is saved.

Comment: Was going to write a long, detailed answer, but @JarekTkaczyk has it spot on: `DB::beginTransaction()` followed by `DB::rollback()` if fail or `DB::commit()` if success.

Comment: If you want to add that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Laravel's `DB::beginTransaction()`, `DB::commit()` and `DB::rollback()` functions to prevent any stray information getting saved to the database. Take the following rough example:

```
public function save(){
  DB::beginTransaction();
  try {
    $parent = new Parent();
    $parent->save();
    $child = new Child();
    $parent->children()->save($child);
    DB::commit();
  } catch(Exception $e()) {
    Log::error($e->getMessage());
    DB::rollback();
  }
}
```

Basically, using a `try { ... } catch() { ... }` block with `DB::beginTransaction()`, `DB::commit()` and `DB::rollback()`, you can try saving something to the database, and if no exceptions are caught, `DB::commit()` the changes. If something goes horribly, terribly wrong, and exception will be caught, the error message will be logged and the changes will be discarded using `DB::rollback()`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ah, woops, nice catch Lukas